# Creating xml like the below format

Tags: c#

I want to create a XML file in csharp like the below format pls help me with the code

```
  <MasterEntries>
  <fruit>Apple</fruit>
  <animal>Fox</animal>
  <color>Violet</color>
  </MasterEntries>
```

Comment: Edited to indent the code block...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if you have .NET 3.5 available to you, I'd recommend you use LINQ to XML. For example:

```
XElement master = new XElement("MasterEntries",
    new XElement("fruit", "Apple"),
    new XElement("animal", "Fox"),
    new XElement("color", "Violet"));
```

That's about as simple as it gets :)

EDIT: Okay, in .NET 2.0 it's a bit more cumbersome. Something like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("MasterEntries");
doc.AppendChild(root);
XmlElement fruit = doc.CreateElement("fruit");
fruit.InnerText = "Apple";
root.AppendChild(fruit);
XmlElement animal = doc.CreateElement("animal");
animal.InnerText = "Fox";
root.AppendChild(animal);
XmlElement color = doc.CreateElement("color");
color.InnerText = "Violet";
root.AppendChild(color);
```

There may well be simpler ways of doing this, but I don't know them...

Once you've got an `XElement`/`XDocument`/`XmlDocument`, you can call `Save` to save it to a file.

Comment: Finish the job... that doesn't "create a XML file" :)